# If Request faild in Powershell. How to fix?

Tags: powershell, shell

Hey Guys I tried to work with if-requests inside Powershell... Long story short. I have the following skript-syntax

```
$var= Read-Host "add, edit or move?"
if($var="add" -or "adduser")  
{
$PWD1 = Read-Host "Bitte vergeben Sie ein Std.-Password für die User? "
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $PWD1 -AsPlainText -Force
$filepath = Read-Host -Prompt "Bitte geben Sie den Pfad zur CSV Datei ein: "
#Datei Importieren
$users = Import-Csv $filepath
$class = Read-Host -Prompt "......." 
$group = Read-Host -Prompt "......."
$ou = "OU=$class,OU=$group,DC=maintstserver,DC=local"
ForEach ($user in $users)
{
$fname = $user.'First Name'
$lname = $user.'Last Name'
$fullname = "$fname $lname"
$department = $user.'Department'
$Mail = $user.'Mailadresse'
$upn = $user.'UPN'
$username = $upn.Split("@")[0]
New-ADUser -Name $fullname -SamAccountName $username -Enabled $true -GivenName $fname -Surname $lname -UserPrincipalName $upn -Path $ou -AccountPassword $securePassword -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True 
echo "Ein Benutzerkonto wurde fuer $lname , $fname unter $ou angelegt"
}
if ($var="show" -or "list")
{
Code........
}
```

Now to my Problem, For examble if I type "show", in my case the skript starts at the first request. I dont know why, any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curly brackets dont look to be balanced. It looks like there should be 1 more `}`

Additionally in your if statement you should use -eq as opposed to =

```
if($var -eq "add" -or "adduser")
```

When you use the single = sign you are setting the value. You are saying $var is now equal to "add"

Comment: Ok, i think we have 2 problems here. 

Under this line: $ou = "OU=$class,OU=$group,DC=maintstserver,DC=local"
try adding a '}'. I think you have missed closing your first block.